# woocommerce, вывод товаров и подкатегорий

Tags: php, wordpress, плагин, woocommerce

Здравствуйте, подскажите как вывести товары и подкатегории на одной странице?

Answer (score 1):

WooCommerce > Настройки > Товары > Отображение > На странице магазина (Показать оба варианта). // на странице магазина